Ask user to provide required information
Could you please advise if it's possible to request more information from the user during the first login using a required action? Is it feasible for this required action to redirect the user to a data-providing form processed by a separate spring-boot application integrated with Keycloak? Would any token be available at this point so that only users going through the data provision stage have access to the endpoint?
Thank you for any hint!
